# Why is my JS button not updating anything when I click it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an idle game for fun and the button I use to give you something is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Keys</title>
<script>
var keys = 0;
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="You have " + keys + " keys.";
}
function increase_keys() {
keys++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="increase_keys()">Make Keys</button>
<p id="count"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried giving the button an ID an detecting when it is clicked, but that doesn't seem to work either:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Keys</title>
<script>
var keys = 0;
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="You have " + keys + " keys.";
}
if(document.getElementById('give_key').clicked == true) {
keys++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="give_key">Make Keys</button>
<p id="count"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything else works: I can change the value of `keys` to any number and it displays correctly, it's just this one button. I am sure it is not anything I'm using, I copied the code to my device and got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of the code by *mti2935*. It is not using global variables, instead the code reads the key count from the page, increases the number by 1 and updates the page. There is no need to call the function when the page is loaded, the initial value is already displayed on the page at load time.

It also displays "1 key", "2 keys", etc. Little touches like that is what will differentiate you from the average developer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Keys</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="increase_keys()">Make Keys</button>
    <p>You have <span id="count">0</span> key<span id="plural">s</span>.</p>  
  </body>
  <script>
    function increase_keys() {
      var oldKeyCount = document.getElementById("count").innerHTML;
      var newKeyCount = parseInt(oldKeyCount,10)+1;
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = newKeyCount;
      if (newKeyCount=="1") {
        document.getElementById("plural").innerHTML="";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("plural").innerHTML="s";
      }
    }
  </script> 
</html>
```

I created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/texasswede/m75kzqr3/

Comment: I hadn't even thought about updating, I thought JS magically updated everything. Ignorance is not bliss in the programming world, I guess. Thank you (and everyone else) for the feedback and answers. If I can ask you something though, why put the `<script>` tag after the content? I've heard people putting Internal CSS after the body to make the page load faster, is it the same for JS?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are seeing is that the p element which is being set by the `document.getelementbyid`, Is only being updated when the page loads.

Rather put the function which sets the p element in its own function and then use the `setInterval` JS function on the loop. (Look it you want to learn it’s functionality)

In other words, the variable is updating, it’s the text that’s not.
Your code for this should look like this:

```
function setkeys() {
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="You have " + keys + " keys.";
}
setInterval(setkeys, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You should place JS at the bottom of the `body`.

**2)** You are rendering the text message only once. You should update it after every button click

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Keys</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="increase_keys()">Make Keys</button>
  <p id="count"></p>

  <script>
    var keys = 0;

    function render() {
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "You have " + keys + " keys.";
    }

    function increase_keys() {
      keys++;
      render()
    }
    
    // Render first time only
    render()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button, it calls the `increase_keys()` function.  The `increase_keys()` increments the value of `keys`, but it doesn't do anything else after that.  So, the new value of `keys` is never displayed.

I re-organized your program a little, to create a new function `showkeys()`, which displays the value of `keys`.  `showkeys()` is called from within `increase_keys()`, so that the value of `keys` is displayed after it is incremented.  `showkeys()` is also called from `windows.onload`, so that the value of `keys` is displayed when the page loads.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Keys</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="increase_keys()">Make Keys</button>
    <p id="count"></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    var keys = 0;
    window.onload = function() {
      showkeys();
    }
    function increase_keys() {
      keys++;
      showkeys();
    }
    function showkeys() {
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="You have " + keys + " keys.";
    }
  </script> 
</html>
```